# php - chart for xor bitwise operator ^?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, xor

Is there a char with all the outputs? Or is the only way to figure them out is with trial and error?

For example

```
    <?php

    echo "A" ^ "{"; //outputs :

    ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily make such a chart with a loop. But XORing two characters into another is not really what XOR does or should primarily be used for.

Comment: Keep in mind that results may vary for non-ascii-characters, based upon encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for such a chart; the operation is perfectly predictable without one. Bitwise operations on PHP strings are performed on the individual bytes making up the string; for instance, in your example:

```
ord("A") = 0x41
ord("{") = 0x7b
           0x41 ^ 0x7b = 0x3a
                     chr(0x3a) = ":"
```

Comment: +1, with the correction that it's not done on the "ordinal values of characters", but on the *byte representation of the string*, which varies by encoding. You could have the string "A" encoded in a non-ASCII-compatible encoding like UTF-16, where its value is/may be `feff0041`.

Comment: Right, that's probably a better wording. I wasn't happy with "ordinal value" but couldn't think of anything better - the PHP.net manual page for `ord()` used the even worse phrasing "ASCII value of character"!

Comment: How exactly does 0x41 ^ 0x7b = 0x3a?